# populate text area with text when a link is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have two HTML text areas with  id=textarea1, id=textarea2 and list as below

- Orange
- Apple

When I focus on textarea1 and click on Orange, the text should be populated in textarea1. When focus is on textarea2 and text clicked, the text should populate in textarea2.

```html
<div id=fruits>
  <table>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>
            orange
            <li>
              apple
            </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea id="textarea1" style="width: 99%; height: 100px;"></textarea>
        <textarea id="textarea2" style="width: 99%; height: 100px;"></textarea>
      


      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable to remember which textarea you focused on. Then when you click on one of the items, copy it into the textarea.

```js
var textarea;
$("textarea").focus(function() {
  textarea = $(this);
});

$("li").click(function() {
  if (textarea) {
    var text = $(this).text().trim();
    textarea.val(function(i, oldval) {
        if (oldval.length) {
            return oldval + '\n' + text;
        } else {
            return text;
        }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=fruits>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>
            orange
            <li>
              apple
            </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea id="textarea1" style="width: 99%; height: 100px;"></textarea>
        <textarea id="textarea2" style="width: 99%; height: 100px;"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Got it. The snippet provided is replacing the previous selection (apple replacing orange). If I have to show the text clicked in a new line each time, should i just use /n and then append the previous one?

Comment: Yes, you could do that.

Comment: My Text areas are getting generated using ng-repeat, how can i generate a new id for each text area?

Comment: I tried using $index and it worked. Thanks for the snippet.

Comment: I am not getting the selection in the new line without replacing with the old value. Am I missing something here? I used                                                                 var newLine = notes.length === 0 ? '' : '\n'

Comment: @khan I've changed the code so it doesn't use the ID, it just saves the element itself in the variable. I've shown how to add the newlines.